# I get "The following layers were not correctly generated." error (Raster -> Extraction -> Contour) QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, error, contour

No matter what parameters I enter for the contouring, I always get the response in the log of "The following layers were not correctly generated." I'm working QGIS 3.6. I am not familiar with this program at all. What can I do to solve this?

[image: Screenshot of the log of the contouring process]

Comment: Hi Adam, and welcome to the GIS Stack Exchange! A good question should include as much information as possible about what you're doing and why. Posting the log response is definitely a good thing, but could you elaborate about the data you're using? The log seems to suggest that you're using an `.img` file to try and extract contours from, which would not work. Also, is there a reason that you need to extract your own contours? That sort of data is usually easy to find for free.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Mac? The error is the same as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321927/unable-to-clip-raster-by-extent-in-qgis-medeira, that is, "command not found". Let's hope that staff at your school can correct the QGIS installation for you, the students.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes I am using a mac. I am in fact using a .img file, that is likely the issue. I am trying to get contours from a DEM. I don't know how to get the file I want in a different file type, but I'll look on different websites where the same stuff is available. I'll let you know how that goes!

Comment: Also, what file type would work? I am trying to extract my own contours for a project that needs specified topographical intervals and they need to be in a form that can be put into Adobe Illustrator as a line to be printed on a laser cutter.